# How does withContext(Dispatchers.Main) affect the main thread?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, withcontext

I'm having a slight trouble understanding how coroutine switches threads. If you're switching back to the main thread, and suppose that the main thread is in the middle of doing something, does the coroutine wait for the current code in the main thread to finish before joining (?) the main thread? Or is it usual that the main thread is always available because executing UI-related codes are supposed to be quick?

I tried Bing AI and Google Bard to explain it. They said that withContext(Dispatchers.Main) does not 'join' the main thread, but failed to mention how it exactly affects the main thread for it to be not joining.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is it usual that the main thread is always available because executing UI-related codes are supposed to be quick?

This is correct, although it's not a requirement. `withContext` will always do the same thing regardless of whether the target thread is occupied or not. It will enqueue your work on that dispatcher's task queue and await its completion, passing the result to you as the return value of `withContext`.

However, in my experience you should never need to use `withContext(Main)`. Instead launch the coroutine on the main thread (which is the default), and switch to a background thread pool only when you have some blocking or computation-heavy work to do. Retrieve the result as the return value of `withContext` and then you can use it to update the UI.

Comment: I read that Dispatchers.Main is referring to a single thread unlike Default and IO which are referring to thread pools. So I need to confirm two more sub-questions to understand what really is happening behind the scenes:

1. Does being a thread or thread pool affect the behavior of switching context?
2. Is "enqueueing" absolute in the main thread that a coroutine doesn't interrupt in the midst of a current series of UI tasks, making withContext(Dispatchers.Main) not "joining" the main thread?

Comment: 1. It doesn't. 2. The block inside `withContext(Main)` executes on the GUI thread, interleaved with other GUI tasks. It doesn't interrupt any task.